# How to disable one radio input from radio group?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i disable the one radio input from the radio group ?

```
<input type="radio" name="radiogrp" value="op1" checked="checked">Option1
<input type="radio" name="radiogrp" value="op2"> Option2
<input type="radio" name="radiogrp" value="op3" > Option3
<input type="radio" name="radiogrp" value="op4"> Option4
```

My question is i want to disable option1 after clicking on any other button

For example:

> when i select option2, than option1 should be disabled

Comment: Look at the [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9834948/601179) I added a cool way for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bySzh/3/) I have just added

Let me know if this is not what you intended

### As requested - posted fiddle answer

```
$('.rd').click(function(){
    $('.rd[value="op1"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');       
});​
```

Comment: it gives some error while checking as answer, something like "You can accept an answer in 1 minute" ... :(

Comment: You should post the answer here, not in jsfiddle

Comment: And you select the radio buttons twice instead of cache the selector result.

Comment: @gdoron - I had to do the second select on the value, I can't cache the whole thing. Pointless

Comment: Wrong... see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9834948/601179). You can test it with `jsPerf` you will notice the difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(":radio").change(function(){

    $(":radio[name='radiogrp']").slice(0,1).attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LTxCt/4/)

Comment: @enigma : i want to disable only option 1, where as option2,option3,option4 must be enabled

Comment: @enigma : it still dosen't work, it disables the lastly selected option

Comment: yet again updated but there are other correct answers already been posted

Comment: yupppp, but thnks for ur time :)

Comment: You should cache the selector result. and could just use `.eq(0)` to get the first element.

Comment: yup caching is related to performance i focused on just getting it right, eq and slice seems to run equally fast http://jsperf.com/already

Comment: it shows varying results though but here is the screenshot where it shows both are equally significant http://imgur.com/QALDd

Answer (score 1):

```
var radios = $('input[type="radio"][name="radiogrp"]');
radios.change(function() {
    if (this.value != "op1") {
        radios.filter('[value="op1"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});​
```

I cached the radio buttons, so I don't need to Query the DOM twice.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2GxE/1)

---

Since, after the change, there is no way back, this is more fun way:

```
var radios = $('input[type="radio"][name="radiogrp"]');
var first = $('input[type="radio"][name="radiogrp"][value="op1"]');
radios.not(first).change(function() {
    alert('changed'); // getting called only once.
    first.prop('disabled', true);
    radios.unbind('change');
});​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2GxE/2/)

Comment: @gdoron - true, I agree. This is a better method, and you've also used  prop - which I assume is the new way. How is it different from attr?

Comment: @ITppl. there was missing `{` try it again

Comment: @gdoron : Now it's 5n, thnks ... :)

Comment: @JibiAbraham. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: @gdoron tx. I shall look into it

Comment: @ITppl. look at the update, thanks for the question! it was fun.

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy, use jQuery's attribute selector. Here is an example of disabling the radio button with value `op3`

```
$('input[value="op3"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/rWjYj/)

---

Here is your **solution**

```
var radios =  $('input[name=radiogrp]'); //Cache all the radio button
radios.click(function() { 
//Attach a function to the click event of all radio button

    if(this.value!='op1') { //Check if currently click button has value of op1
        radios.filter('[value="op1"]').prop('disabled', true); //if not disable the first
    }
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/rWjYj/3/)

Comment: **1.** Use `prop` instead of `attr`. **2.** `$(this).val()` => `this.value` **3.** Cache the selector result.

Comment: @gdoron, One thing is `this.value` faster than `$(this).val()`?

Comment: Yes it is, it doesn't need to create jQuery object. and do a lot of things just to get the value.

Comment: You still select twice the DOM

Comment: I miss use the `prop` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('input[value="op2"]').click(function(e)
     {
         $('input[value="op1"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3CdZU/

Answer (score 1):

I am using jquery mobile with fancy dynamic styling, and I found that after performing the disable, I needed to explicitly issue an refresh using the checkboxradio("refresh") method call so that the styling would reflect the change. You can chain the method call, though, so it might look like this:

```
$('.rd').click(function(){
  $('.rd[value="op1"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled').checkboxradio("refresh");
});​
```

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/updating-the-value-of-enhanced-form-elements-does-not-work.html

While I appreciate gdoron's deeper, more technical, more efficient, more comprehensive approach, I believe that sometimes (just sometimes) the easier reading and shorter coding of Jibi Abraham's approach is warranted, especially in an otherwise lightweight situation.

I realize this isn't a distinct answer, but I don't have enough reputation to do a comment yet.